# angularjs ng-repeat is not looping through the modal box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi everybody so I am building this assignment for a class, and I have reached a wall. The ng-repeat is not looping through the modal box. It loops through the first item but then stops. Any help? Here is a jsbin to illustrate.

http://jsbin.com/OZaGipAg/2/edit

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Looks fine, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: If you click on box that isn't the first box you will see that all the other modal boxes just load the first picture. THis is what I was trying to say but I am not very good at explaining though I am trying to improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source with Firebug, your code looks to be doing what its supposed to be doing.  Each list item has a unique picture for the thumbnail and for the modal window in the html.  This is not a looping issue.  The problem is that all of the thumbnails are loading the same modal window (first one).

***Update***
I was able to get your thumbnails to load the appropriate image by tying the id generated for each modal window to the `$index` of the `ng-repeat`.  Look at the following lines:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$index}}">

<a href='#' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$index}}" >
```

These two lines are the only place that you used the id.  Change lines 24 and 44 to match.

Comment: Yes this is the problem I am having that the same modal window is loading. I guess I am not very good at explaining the problem.

Comment: @ChadWatkins Check my update.  I was able to get the thumbnails to load with this fix inside your jsbin example.